# Passing a user input as a string into a function

Tags: r

```
csvToJSON <- function (fileUrl, fileName) {
  library(rjson)
  data <- read.csv(fileUrl)
  jsonData <- toJSON(as.list(data))
  fileName <- paste0(fileName, ".json")
  write(jsonData, cat(fileName))
}
```

I created this function to convert csv files into JSON files. 
For the csvToJSON function that I had, one of the input parameters is fileName, and I want that to be the name of the json file to be outputted, so I have passed fileName to the write() function at the end. However, the write() function requires it to be in the form of write(jsonData, "fileName"). How can I solve this problem? In another word, how can I add quotation marks over the input fileName?

Comment: Please remove the `cat` around the `fileName`.  Here, I am assuming that the `fileName` passed is a string so, you don't need any quotes.  can you show how you are calling the function `csvToJSON`

Comment: csvToJSON("http://data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD", jsonData)
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
 
 Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection

Comment: This is what I got after calling it

Comment: Can you try with `csvToJSON("data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/…", "jsonData")` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that and it actually works. However, I am just wondering how can I add a quotation mark in the code instead of doing that manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass unquoted column names and use it as a string in the function we can use `deparse` and `substitute`

```
csvToJSON <- function (fileUrl, fileName) {
    fileName <- deparse(substitute(fileName))
    data <- read.csv(fileUrl)
    jsonData <- toJSON(as.list(data))
    fileName <- paste0(fileName, ".json")
    write(jsonData, fileName)
} 

csvToJSON("data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/", jsonData)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is possible to use the same method to pass quoted names to the fileUrl?

Comment: @KaihuaHou If you pass `"data.baltimorecity.gov/api/views/dz54-2aru/"` without quotes it will not work since it will consider `/` as the division operator.